# Using jQuery POST inside a Javascript function - not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So this an assignment I need help with. I will include the code below. I need to use the jQuery/Ajax post to send two values to my database. All the code is correct, and I have tested it in a separate test file. However, it will not work inside of a function in my javascript. Any reason why this is occurring?

main html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shootin' Exposition</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rye' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
html,body {
  background: url(frontierland.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
  -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
  -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
  background-size: cover;         /* Generic*/
  font-family: 'Rye', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.help
{
  background-color: #555555;
  width:250px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.score
{
  background-color: wheat;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color:saddlebrown;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var tm, crockett;
    $(document).ready(
 function () {
 //start the game
 $('#start').click(function () {

     init();
 }
)

 $('#stop').click(function () {
     flush();
 }
)

 }
);
    var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var connectionstring="Data Source=<localhose"

    function init() {
        // create crockett
        crockett = $('<img>').attr({
            'src': 'site.gif'
        }).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': 75,
            top: -10,
            left: -10
        });

        //append it to body
        $(document.body).append(crockett);

        //start bullseyeing
        do_bullseye();

    }

    function do_bullseye() {
        //take a random color
        var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' +
                    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' +
                    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';


        //generate random position
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());
//            var x = $(window).width() / 2;
//            var y = $(window).height() / 2;
//            crockettx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
//            crocketty = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());

        crockett = $('<img>').attr({
            'src': 'site.gif'
        }).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': 75,
            top: Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height()),
            left: Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width())
        });
        $(document.body).append(crockett);

        //decorating the bullseye
        bullseye = $('<span>').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            height: '25px',
            width: '25px',
            'background-color': '#FF0000',
            'border-color': '#550000',
            'border-style': 'dotted',
            'border-width': '5px',
            'border-radius': '25px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '25px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '25px',
            top: y - 12, //offsets
            left: x - 12 //offsets
        });

        //append it to body
        $(document.body).append(bullseye);

        //bind the hit on click event
        bullseye.bind('click', function (e) {
            crockett.stop();
            //you won
            won();
            //hide the bullseye
            hit(e.pageX, e.pageY, $(e.target));
        });

        //call crockett to chase the bullseye
        chase(x, y, bullseye);

        //bullseyes are endless
        tm = window.setTimeout('do_bullseye()', 1500);

    }


    function chase(x, y, bullseye) {
        //crockett gets the bullseye
        crockett.animate({
            top: y - 35,
            left: x - 35
        }, 1500, function () {
            //hit the bullseye
            hit(x, y, bullseye);
            //you lose
            lose();
        });
    }


    function hit(x, y, bullseye) {
        bullseye.animate({
            height: '100px',
            width: '100px',
            'border-radius': '200px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '200px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '200px',
            opacity: 0,
            top: y-50,
            left: x-50

        }, 100, function () {
            bullseye.remove();
        });

    }

    function lose() {
        $("#crockett").html(parseInt($("#crockett").html()) + 1);
        crockett.remove();
        if (parseInt($("#crockett").html()) == 10) {
            alert("You lost!");
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/");
        }
    }

    function won() {
        crockett.remove();
        crockett.stop();
        $("#you").html(parseInt($("#you").html()) + 1);
        if (parseInt($("#you").html()) == 10)
        {
            alert("You won!");

            //calling teh post function which does not work

            post();

            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/");
        }
    }
    function flush() {

        crockett.remove();
        clearTimeout(tm);
        crockett.stop();
        bullseye.hide();

    }

    //this is the function that I am talking about
    function post() {
      $.post("save_score.php", {you: you, crockett: crockett}); 
    }


</script>

<!-- Start of JQuery Code -->

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<!-- End of JQuery Code -->

</head>
<body style="cursor:crosshair; background-color:#222222;">
    <div class="help">
        <p>
            Use mouse-clicks to get the bullseye before Davy Crockett 
does...
            <br />
            Fullscreen mode helps
            <br />
            Scores are: You vs. Crockett
            <br />
            <span href="#" id="start" style="color: 
#FDFF00;">Play</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
                href="#" id="stop" style="color: #FDFF00;">Stop</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <span class="score">P1:<span id="you">0</span> / P2:<span 
id="crockett">0</span><br />
    </span>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

'save_score.php':

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

  $Player1 = 'You';
  $Player2 = 'Crockett'

  $you      = $_POST["you"];
  $crockett = $_POST['crockett'];

  //echo $name;
  //echo $score;

  //Send Scores from Player 1 to Database 
  $save1   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) 
    VALUES ('" . $Player1 . "', , '" . $you . "')";

  $success = $mysqli->query($save1);

  if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$mysqli->error);
  }

  //Send Scores from Player 2 to Database 
   $save2   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) 
    VALUES ('" . $Player2 . "', , '" . $crockett . "')";

  $success = $mysqli->query($save2);

  if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$mysqli->error);
  }

?>
```

Gyazo Console Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: For one thing, you have 2 commas `"', ,` <<< right there.

Comment: Also, your post doesn't appear to have a callback to get called when completed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- appreciate that

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I am just learning jQuery today. What would that look like or where is a source that I can go to that would should me what that looks like?

Comment: do you see an ajax call in your web debugger ? 
If yes check the request content-type header, you should have application/json.
In server side when you log in your 'save_score.php' file, do you see your log appear ?

Comment: @Mcsky this is what I am seeing in my web debugger https://i.gyazo.com/1d3b96ccb05efa219c54625d00ab361b.png

Comment: `ActiveXObject` only exists in Internet Explorer, that's why you get that error. You should try to find a more portable replacment for `ADODB`.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet you are getting an to guess you are getting a `Reference Error: you is not defined.` or `Reference Error: crockett is not defined.`. The reason for this is because in your function definition you are not listing parameters.

Thus, we you invoke your function you don't place an arguments, which leads to the Error.

Try defining your function this way:

```
function post(you, crockett) {
  $.post("save_score.php", {you: you, crockett: crockett}); 
}
```

And then when you invoke it, try invoking it with this:

```
post('me', [1,2,3]);
```

You should have those values in your Php script.

If you want more info to understand what is going on exactly, the reason this doesn't work is because you have not declare a you or crockett variable in the current lexical scope.

You should check out this book: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

It will enrich your javascript abilities, as it has mine.

Cheers.

Comment: I will edit my post with a gyazo screenshot of the console! Thank you!

Comment: Anytime mate! (thumbsup)

Comment: Just added a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Variable **you** is not defined, fix this and try putting all the code inside Jquery scope

```
$(document).ready(
var tm, crockett; //var you is missing
 function () {
 //start the game
 $('#start').click(function () {

     init();
 }
)

 $('#stop').click(function () {
     flush();
 }
)

 }

// <--put your code here
);
```

Additionally see this about AxtiveXOcject, is only supported by IE :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was a combination of errors from all around! There was misplaced code from other things that I had tried and also certain quotes and commas were misplaced. I needed to initialize my variables before sending them via the post function. Probably the most helpful tip out of all of this was to use the "web debugger" built into Chrome! So helpful in giving me valuable feedback on errors. I also disabled my adblocker just in case, I saw that one of the errors I was getting might be caused by it, so it might be helpful to do so. Anyways, I am posting my completed and working code. Thanks for all your help everyone!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shootin' Exposition</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rye' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      background: url(frontierland.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      /* For WebKit*/
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      /* Mozilla*/
      -o-background-size: cover;
      /* Opera*/
      background-size: cover;
      /* Generic*/
      font-family: 'Rye', serif;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .help {
      background-color: #555555;
      width: 250px;
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    .score {
      background-color: wheat;
      opacity: 0.7;
      color: saddlebrown;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var tm, crockett;
    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        //start the game
        $('#start').click(function() {

          init();
        })

        $('#stop').click(function() {
          flush();
        })

      }
    );

    function init() {
      // create crockett
      crockett = $('<img>').attr({
        'src': 'site.gif'
      }).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'z-index': 75,
        top: -10,
        left: -10
      });

      //append it to body
      $(document.body).append(crockett);

      //start bullseyeing
      do_bullseye();

    }

    function do_bullseye() {
      //take a random color
      var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' +
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' +
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';


      //generate random position
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());
      //            var x = $(window).width() / 2;
      //            var y = $(window).height() / 2;
      //            crockettx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
      //            crocketty = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());

      crockett = $('<img>').attr({
        'src': 'site.gif'
      }).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'z-index': 75,
        top: Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height()),
        left: Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width())
      });
      $(document.body).append(crockett);

      //decorating the bullseye
      bullseye = $('<span>').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        height: '25px',
        width: '25px',
        'background-color': '#FF0000',
        'border-color': '#550000',
        'border-style': 'dotted',
        'border-width': '5px',
        'border-radius': '25px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '25px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '25px',
        top: y - 12, //offsets
        left: x - 12 //offsets
      });

      //append it to body
      $(document.body).append(bullseye);

      //bind the hit on click event
      bullseye.bind('click', function(e) {
        crockett.stop();
        //you won
        won();
        //hide the bullseye
        hit(e.pageX, e.pageY, $(e.target));
      });

      //call crockett to chase the bullseye
      chase(x, y, bullseye);

      //bullseyes are endless
      tm = window.setTimeout('do_bullseye()', 1500);

    }


    function chase(x, y, bullseye) {
      //crockett gets the bullseye
      crockett.animate({
        top: y - 35,
        left: x - 35
      }, 1500, function() {
        //hit the bullseye
        hit(x, y, bullseye);
        //you lose
        lose();
      });
    }


    function hit(x, y, bullseye) {
      bullseye.animate({
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px',
        'border-radius': '200px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '200px',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '200px',
        opacity: 0,
        top: y - 50,
        left: x - 50

      }, 100, function() {
        bullseye.remove();
      });

    }

    function lose() {
      $("#crockett").html(parseInt($("#crockett").html()) + 1);
      crockett.remove();
      if (parseInt($("#crockett").html()) == 10) {
        alert("You lost!");

        post();

        window.location.replace("http://www.yahoo.com/");
      }
    }

    function won() {
      crockett.remove();
      crockett.stop();
      $("#you").html(parseInt($("#you").html()) + 1);
      if (parseInt($("#you").html()) == 10) {
        alert("You won!");

        post();

        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/");
      }
    }

    function flush() {

      crockett.remove();
      clearTimeout(tm);
      crockett.stop();
      bullseye.hide();

    }

    //
    function post() {

      var you = "You";
      var crockett = "Crockett";
      var you_score = parseInt($("#you").html());
      var crockett_score = parseInt($("#crockett").html());

      $.post("save_score.php", {
          name1: you,
          name2: crockett,
          score1: you_score,
          score2: crockett_score
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          alert("Scores were saved: " + data);
        });
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Start of JQuery Code -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <!-- End of JQuery Code -->

</head>

<body style="cursor:crosshair; background-color:#222222;">
  <div class="help">
    <p>
      Use mouse-clicks to get the bullseye before Davy Crockett does...
      <br /> Fullscreen mode helps
      <br /> Scores are: You vs. Crockett
      <br />
      <span href="#" id="start" style="color: #FDFF00;">Play</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span href="#" id="stop" style="color: #FDFF00;">Stop</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <span class="score">P1:<span id="you">0</span> / P2:<span id="crockett">0</span><br />
  </span>
  <br />
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

  $Player1 = $_POST['name1'];
  $Player2 = $_POST['name2'];

  $Player1_Score = $_POST['score1'];
  $Player2_Score = $_POST['score2'];

  //Send Scores from Player 1 to Database 
  $save1   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES ('$Player1', '$Player1_Score')";

  $success = $mysqli->query($save1);

  if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$mysqli->error);

    echo "unsuccessfully";
  }

  //Send Scores from Player 2 to Database 
  $save2   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES ('$Player2', '$Player2_Score')";

  $success = $mysqli->query($save2);

  if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$mysqli->error);
    echo "unsuccessfully";
  }

  echo "successfully";
?>
```

**Added the above as Code Snippets for readability.**

Answer (score -1):

What error did you get?
Did you inspect(console) to see if the jquery post values are not empty?

**Ensuer that the post value in php are not empty**

```
$you      = (isset($_POST["you"]) AND !empty($_POST["you"])) ? $_POST["you"] : "empty you";
$crockett = (isset($_POST['crockett']) AND !empty($_POST['crockett'])) ? $_POST['crockett'] : "empty crockett";
```

Your queries are not correct;

**Change:**

```
$save1   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES ('" . $Player1 . "', , '" . $you . "')";
```

**to**

```
$save1   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES ('$Player1', '$you')";
```

**change**

```
$save2   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) 
    VALUES ('" . $Player2 . "', , '" . $crockett . "')";
```

**to**

```
$save2   = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) 
    VALUES ('$Player2', '$crockett')";
```

You have unnecessary commas and quotations.

Cheers

Comment: I will edit my post with a gyazo screenshot of the console! Thank you!

Comment: *"Your queries are not correct"* --- Both `'" . $var . "'` and `'$var'` do the same thing, so there's no need to change the quotes. Saying it's incorrect is false.

Comment: That's true but unnecessary.  The main thing is there are extra commas.